# Model not loading after using plyer filechooser

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, filechooser

I have a trained model which is loading in the main python file. It is working and giving predictions when I choose kivy's FileChooseListView but I wanted to make it better so I used plyer filechooser which did load images but the problem is now my model is not loading. Its not giving any error either. Can anyone tell what the problem is?

I have tried correcting it and debugging but nothing is happening.

**main.py**

```
class UploadScreen(Screen):
    def file_chooser(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)


    def selected(self, filename):
        try:
            self.ids.my_image.source = filename[0]
            print(filename[0])

            CATEGORIES = ['Diving Side',  # 1.
                          'Golf-Swing-Front',  # 2.
                          'Golf-Swing-Side',  # 3.
                          'Kicking-Front',  # 4.
                          'Kicking-Side',  # 5.
                          'Lifting',  # 6
                          'Riding-Horse',  # 7
                          'Run-Side',  # 8.
                          'SkateBoarding-Front',  # 9
                          'Swing-Bench',  # 10.
                          'Swing-SideAngle',  # 11
                          'Walk-Front'  # 12.
                          ]
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./model/model") /// Model is not loading
            size = (90, 90)
            img_array = cv2.imread(filename[0])
            pd_array = []
            im = cv2.resize(img_array, size, cv2.INTER_AREA)
            im = im.astype('float32')
            pd_array.append(im)

            np_image = np.array(pd_array)
            print("NP array ")
            print(np_image.shape)
            predictions = model.predict(np_image)
            top = np.argmax(predictions)
            print(predictions)
            # top=top-1
            print(top)
            print("prediction is "+CATEGORIES[top])

            results = CATEGORIES[top]
            print(results)
            name = results
            # Update the label
            self.ids.name_label.text = name
            print("Captured")
        except:
            pass
```

**.kv**

```
<UploadScreen>:
    name: 'upload'
    id: upload
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            # rgba: 0.439,0.501,0.564,1 
            rgb: 0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 1
        Rectangle: 
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    MDGridLayout:
        rows:5
        cols:1            
        spacing: 25
        padding: 25  
        MDLabel:
            id: name_label
            text: "Results"
            bold: True
            font_size: 35
            color: 0.137, 0.156, 0.419, 1
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Select Image'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: None, None
            width: root.width*1
            height: root.height*0.1
            md_bg_color: 0.258, 0.372, 0.921, 1
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.3}
            on_press: root.file_chooser()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size: root.width, root.height
            padding: 50
            spacing: 20    

            Image:
                id: my_image
                source: ""     

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Back'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: None, None
            width: root.width*1
            height: root.height*0.1
            md_bg_color: 0.258, 0.372, 0.921, 1
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.3}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```